# Dynamically get the value of management group id during arm template deployment

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-management-groups

I would like to confirm that there is no way to dynamically get the value of management group id during arm template deployment scoped to the MG level.

I mean something similar to the ARM template function *subscription()* which returns an object with an *Id* property that can be used in the template.

I know there is no *managementGroup()* function, but I am wondering if there is any other trick to avoid having to add a parameter to the template.

Comment: perhaps, you would consider making this question a little better, by including code. you mention, subscription and managementGroup. Obviously, I can look up those functions on my own, but you should illustrate where and how you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't possible today but it's on the backlog... If you want to share your use case for it I'll add that as well to help prioritize.

Answer (score 0):

There is no function like `subscription()` to get the management Id directly. But you can use the function [`tenantResourceId()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/template-functions-resource#tenantresourceid) to get the management group Id like this:

```
tenantResourceId('Microsoft.Management/managementGroups', 'groupName')
```

Answer (score 0):

To fetch a azurepolicy id that was existing at management group level

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).